# How do I Get Maximum and Minimum Data Length for All Columns on All Tables in a SQL Server database Using One Query?

Tags: sql-server

I am currently trying to get details of maximum and minimum data length (using DATALENGTH / LEN) for all columns on all tables on my SQL Server database.

Currently what I can do is I can show the details of the actual length of a column when setting up the table, maximum and minimum data length but only for one table.

I have about 50 tables that I want to check, so instead of checking each table one by one, could anyone assist in getting the result for all tables within one single query?

This is the query that I currently use (I found the query from an online source):

```
DECLARE @TSQL VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @TableName sysname = 'MyTable'
SELECT  @TSQL = @TSQL + 'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(sc.name, '''') + ' AS ColumnName, 
        ' + QUOTENAME(t.name, '''') + ' AS DataType, ' +
        QUOTENAME(sc.max_length, '''') + ' AS ActualLength,
        MIN(DATALENGTH(' + QUOTENAME(sc.name) + ')) AS MinUsedLength,
        MAX(DATALENGTH(' + QUOTENAME(sc.name) + ')) AS MaxUsedLength FROM '+@TableName+ char(10) +' UNION '
FROM sys.columns sc
        JOIN sys.types t on t.system_type_id = sc.system_type_id and t.name != 'sysname'
WHERE sc.OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(@TableName)
SET @TSQL = LEFT(@TSQL, LEN(@TSQL)-6)
EXEC(@TSQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max) = N'';
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + N'SELECT ''' 
            + C.TABLE_SCHEMA + N''' AS TABLE_SCHEMA, ''' 
            + C.TABLE_NAME + N''' AS TABLE_NAME, ''' 
            + C.COLUMN_NAME + N''' AS COLUMN_NAME, '
            + N'MIN(DATALENGTH([' + C.COLUMN_NAME + N'])) AS MIN_LENGTH, '
            + N'MAX(DATALENGTH([' + C.COLUMN_NAME + N'])) AS MAX_LENGTH '
            + N'FROM [' + +  C.TABLE_SCHEMA + N'].[' + C.TABLE_NAME 
            +N'] UNION ALL '
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS T 
       JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C 
          ON T.TABLE_SCHEMA = C.TABLE_SCHEMA AND 
             T.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME
WHERE  TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE';
SET @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) - 10);
EXEC (@SQL);
```

Comment: How can I add columns to get the data type and actual length that was set during table creation as well? 


And when I ran the query, for some tables it returned me an error like this: "The identifier that starts with 'Payback period including sunk costs [years])) AS MIN_LENGTH, MAX(DATALENGTH([Payback period including sunk costs [years])) AS MA' is too long. Maximum length is 128." 


Payback period including sunk costs [years] is the name for one of the columns in a table and I dont think it exceed the max length of 128